# How to "inject" a different ControlTemplate in a CustomControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a WPF project for a CustomControl.
It has a .cs with some Dependency Properties:

```
namespace CustomControlLib
{     
    public class CustomControl1 : Control
    {
        static CustomControl1()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
        }
        public Style IcStyle
        {
            get { return (Style)GetValue(IcStyleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IcStyleProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IcStyleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IcStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(CustomControl1));
        .....
```

and XAML code for **two** ControlTemplates in its Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:CustomControlLib">
    
     <Style x:Key="ListBoxInputControl" TargetType="{x:Type ic:CustomControl1}"> 
         <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ic:CustomControl1}">
                        <Grid x:Name="ListRoot">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition  SharedSizeGroup="Labels"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="320"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label
                                x:Name="PART_NameLabel2"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Margin="1">
                            <Label.Content>
                                ...
                            </Label.Content>
                            </Label>

                            <ListBox
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ...}"
                                SelectedIndex="{TemplateBinding ...}"
                                SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding ...}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxInputControl" TargetType="{x:Type ic:CustomControl1}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ic:CustomControl1}">
                        <Grid
                        x:Name="ComboRoot">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                      
                            
                            <Label
                                Grid.Column="0"                           
                                <Label.Content>
                                ...
                                </Label.Content>
                            </Label>
                            <ComboBox
                                x:Name="PART_ComboBox"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding ...}"
                                ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ...}"
                                SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding ...}">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

(and there is a third one, for a TextBox)
I want to use the CustomControl like this:

```
<Window
    x:Class="CoCa.Views.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:CustomControlLib;assembly=CustomControlLib">
    ...
<ic:CustomControl1
   Name1="PLF"                             
   IcSelectedIndex="{Binding Path=.....}"       
   IcItemsSource="{Binding Source=...}"
   IcStyle="{StaticResource ic:ListBoxInputControl}"/>
<ic:CustomControl1
   Name1="PLF"                             
   IcSelectedIndex="{Binding Path=.....}"       
   IcItemsSource="{Binding Source=...}"
   IcStyle="{StaticResource ic:ComboBoxInputControl}"/>
```

I was hoping to be able to plug the right ControlTemplate in the CustomControl1 like this.
But alas: it does not work like this.
I get the message: "The resource "ic:ComboBoxInputControl" could not be resolved."

How would it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference the `Style` using its `x:Key`:

```
IcStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxInputControl}"/>
```

You also need to merge the `ResourceDictionary` where the styles are defined into the scope of the `Window`, e.g.:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CustomControlLib;component/themes/generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: I did what you suggested: put the ResourceDictionary in my app's App.xaml. Deleted the ic: in the StaticResources. Now at runtime I get "Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.". I get that with IcStyle=  and with Style=

Comment: Does your referenced `Style` set the `Style` property? That's not allowed.

Comment: yes it does.. hoped to inject the ControlTemplate that way, because it is wrapped in   a style in Generic.xaml

Comment: You can set the `Template` property in a `Style` but not the `Style` property.